# Spelled-out number (string) to integer using ICU

Tags: java, kotlin, icu

I need to convert a string to an integer. For example, I would like to convert sixth to 6.

I did the reverse one (6 → sixth) by using IBM's library ICU.

```
private val String.spellout: String
  get() {
    val esFormatter = RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.ENGLISH, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT)
    return esFormatter.format(this.toDouble(), "%spellout-ordinal")
  }
```

I would like to create another method that takes that spelled-out string and converts it to a double (sixth → 6)

Comment: Have you tried http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String- , e.g. `val esFormatter = RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.ENGLISH, RuleBasedNumberFormat.ORDINAL); val n = esFormatter.parse("sixth")`

Comment: `RuleBasedNumberFormat` also has a `parse` method that looks like it is doing what you want.

Comment: You guys are right. I tried that but also used it for invalid strings so it threw exception. I had to wrap it with a try-catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting help from the comments here is my solution, in case anybody else needs it:

```
private val String.numberFromSpelledOut: Boolean
  get() {
    val esFormatter = RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.ENGLISH, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT)
    return try {
      return esFormatter.parse(this)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
      ""
    }
  }
```

This should not throw an exception for invalid spelled-out inputs.

Comment: “This should not throw an exception for invalid spelled-out inputs.”  That's your choice, of course; but in my experience it tends to lead to bigger problems in the long run.  (If it makes sense for this particular need, you could have `numberFromSpelledOut` throw the exception, and then have the caller catch it.  That would be more explicit, and more flexible.  Though if it can throw an exception, it might make more sense as an extension method rather than an extension property.)